# scn file all items rotated

Tags: scenekit, arkit

I have a curtain I want to render in my ARKit app. I added all parts of my curtain (exported as COLLADA) and added them in my `.scn` file and placed them so that they line up properly and form a correct curtain.

Now I have added the file to the ARKit testing app and it seems like all individual objects rotated around the X-axis of their own coordinate system.

Why is this? Does it have something to do with Y vs Z being up?

Comment: Did you use constraints?

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev No I do not, the files have simply been exported by Blender

Answer (score 0):

Blender's coordinate system uses Z-up, but SceneKit uses Y-up. I believe that's where your issue is stemming from.

SCNScene has an initializer with loading options, try using the convertToYUp option. This could be done at runtime or before with a custom command line tool.

Here's an example of how to load a Collada file with the convert Y-up option, then exported to the url destination of your choice.

```
let scene = try? SCNScene(url: daeURL, options: [.convertToYUp: true])
scene.write(to: scnURL, options: nil, delegate: nil, progressHandler: nil)
```

I've been very happy with the results. SceneKit is able to convert not just single objects but multiple objects in complex scenes.

Just remember to apply rotation in Blender before exporting to get good results. I believe the hotkey to apply rotation is Ctrl+A, then R.